# How does the ref callback work in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The `ref` property enables us to capture the value of an uncontrolled component.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
     <input type="text" ref={el => this.setState({ myEl: el })}/>
  }
}
```

How does this work? Presumably `input` is actually a React component that has a property ("prop") `ref` that takes a callback that is invoked with the wrapper component of the field every when `componentDidMount` is called?

Comment: BTW don't mutate state directly! Use `setState`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html):

> #### Adding a Ref to a DOM Element
>
> React supports a special attribute that you can attach to any component. The `ref` attribute takes a callback function, and the callback will be executed immediately after the component is mounted or unmounted.
>
> [...]
>
> React will call the `ref` callback with the DOM element when the component mounts, and call it with `null` when it unmounts.

So the `ref` callback is called after the component is mounted to the DOM, with the underlying DOM element as the sole argument. It is also called after unmounting with the argument `null`.

Comment: Thank you. Can you confirm that even element types that match "real" ones  (eg. input, div) are actually ReactJS components supplied with ReactJS?

Comment: @BenAston Well, when the JSX is finally mounted to the DOM, `input` is mapped to an actual HTML `input`, but when you use JSX, it's translated to `React.createElement` which just creates an object -- but when that's given to the renderer the actual DOM element is mounted.

Comment: Thank you. And `React.createElement` will return an instance of an object that contains the relevant API/wireup for the `ref` property to work?

Comment: @BenAston Yes. Since ref is a prop, it's specially handled in `React.createElement`. The object returned from `createElement` -- a `ReactElement` has an internal ref prop which is then handled by the renderer, it supplies the underlying DOM element to the callback.

Comment: How to update the ref? For example, if I have a table with rows, and they are sorted so the positions are different.